# How to set up a project in Netbeans with a svn repository

Tags: svn, netbeans

I have a svn repository set up which already has some source code.
How should I integrate Netbeans with that repository?

This how I am thinking about doing it to the project (*currently trying it on a test project*):
 1. Create a new project
 2. After selecting it, going to the menu toolbar > Team > Subversion > Checkout
 3. Provide the repo URL, and then selecting the folders trunk, branches and tags (is that correct?)
 4. After doing that all the files have been downloaded at the project root. Now adding all the headers to the "Header Files" logical dir and source files respectively.

Is that a correct workflow?

Comment: You can find full explanations in the documentation [Using Subversion Support in NetBeans IDE](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/subversion.html)

Comment: This documentation link says you need svn client software which links to collab.net page for Netbeans IDE.  There is a download link on that page which brings you to the download for NetBeans which I already have.  All I want to do is utilize svn file:/// and not have to setup a server.  Is there any way to do this without adding anything?